# Windows not appearing in codelite ide

Tags: c++, codelite

Hi i am relitively new to codelite and i have accidently got rid of all the little windows here is the screen.
[Codelite Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fba5d.png)

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEnMI.png)

does anyone know how to get them back up again?

Comment: Are you debugging your application in the first picture. I see no => that points to the currently running line of code. Also it appears your code is edited without saving.

Comment: no i wasnt tyrying to debug it i had just lost all the different veiws i was trieng to switch file but i couldnt because there was no workspace view